# Is SequentialGuidValueGenerator safe to use on Azure?

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core

I'd like to use `SequentialGuidValueGenerator` as a key generator in my Entity Framework Core model. I am concerned though that multiple processes running on the same machine might end up with clashing keys.

Is this class safe for usage like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `SequentialGuidValueGenerator` is safe to use over multiple machines and processes.

Only part of the `Guid` is sequential (based on the current time of the machine in ticks at the moment the `SequentialGuidValueGenerator` class got first initialized and then incremented for each `Guid` generated).

Other parts contain constant (usually the MAC address or something similar) and random values (usually pseudo random generated).

The whole idea behind GUIDs is, that they are guaranteed to be **g**lobally **u**nique. The sequential concept is just a tweak to generate them in a database friendly way that leads to less index fragmentation.

### Algorithms

The [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/883808fa10e7a52316d8e21a74bd983bedfbee56/src/EFCore/ValueGeneration/SequentialGuidValueGenerator.cs#L36) for `SequentialGuidValueGenerator` uses the `Guid.New()` method as the base for its sequential algorithm:

#### Windows:

On Windows, [Guid.New()](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/dd7edf82e36e6c350a2c3fef0a0c2b69e8c11d61/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Guid.Windows.cs#L13) uses the [CoCreateGuid function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateguid):

> The CoCreateGuid function calls the RPC function UuidCreate, which creates a GUID, a globally unique 128-bit integer. Use CoCreateGuid when you need an absolutely unique number that you will use as a persistent identifier in a distributed environment.To a very high degree of certainty, this function returns a unique value – no other invocation, on the same or any other system (networked or not), should return the same value.

The function uses the [UuidCreate function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateguid):

> For security reasons, it is often desirable to keep ethernet addresses on networks from becoming available outside a company or organization. The UuidCreate function generates a UUID that cannot be traced to the ethernet address of the computer on which it was generated. It also cannot be associated with other UUIDs created on the same computer. If you do not need this level of security, your application can use the UuidCreateSequential function, which behaves exactly as the UuidCreate function does on all other versions of the operating system.

#### Unix:

On Unix, [Guid.New()](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/dd7edf82e36e6c350a2c3fef0a0c2b69e8c11d61/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Guid.Unix.cs#L12) just uses random bytes.

#### SequentialGuidValueGenerator

With the retrieved normal `Guid`, a counter is incremented each call (see [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/883808fa10e7a52316d8e21a74bd983bedfbee56/src/EFCore/ValueGeneration/SequentialGuidValueGenerator.cs#L37)) based on the UTC time in ticks when the `SequentialGuidValueGenerator` class got created (see [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/ValueGeneration/SequentialGuidValueGenerator.cs#L27)).

The indexing relevant part of the `Guid` is then updated with the counter (see [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/883808fa10e7a52316d8e21a74bd983bedfbee56/src/EFCore/ValueGeneration/SequentialGuidValueGenerator.cs#L44-L51));

### Further information

We recently reviewed the algorithm on GitHub in the issue [Check that SequentialGuidValueGenerator still matches the SQL Server behavior #19124](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19124) due to potential concerns (unrelated to your question; related to indexing performance) raised by me in [Ensure that generated GUIDs conform to the RFC 4122 standard. #969](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/pull/969).

For just general information of GUIDs and their different formats, the Wikipedia article [Universally unique identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) it a good starting point and also lists the major background papers and references.

Comment: Thanks. Can you cite any references to support your answer? I don't mean programmer blogs, but something in a power reviewed paper?

Comment: I updated the answer with more background information and references.

Comment: Can we guess SequentialGuidValueGenerator guid ? and is it generating based on time?

Comment: @SumeshEs Take a look at the [current implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/ValueGeneration/SequentialGuidValueGenerator.cs). 8 Bytes are a 64 bit counter that just increments and is initialized by the current time in ticks when the app starts. The other 8 bytes are from the default GUID implementation of the OS, which uses a cryptographically secure random number generator (see the [Guid.Unix.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Guid.Unix.cs)). So no, the `Guid` cannot be guessed.

Comment: @lauxjpn I tried sorting the Guids generated from SequentialGuidValueGenerator but it is coming in wrong order.

Comment: @SumeshEs The default `SequentialGuidValueGenerator` is optimized for index performance. You cannot reliably sort guids. The whole concept of guids is, that they are guaranteed to be unique. The way this uniqueness is implemented is not compatible with a reliable way of sorting. But you could replace the default implementation with a custom one, if you want to implement your own algorithm for guid creation. Other ways to get the order in which the rows where created are to use a datetime or timestamp field, or a database trigger with some custom logic, or a good old auto increment column.